# HelpScout Mailbox API 2.0 - How to create an outgoing conversation from a "user" to a "customer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use the Help Scout Mailbox 2.0 API to send renewal invoices to my clients. I'm working with the Ruby help-scout_sdk gem -- but their API is just a Restful JSON thing, Ruby has little to do with it.

It's easy enough to become authenticated and create a conversation:
https://developer.helpscout.com/mailbox-api/endpoints/conversations/create/

```rb
# Auth credentials in an Rails' initializer

data = {
  subject: 'Time for renewal - Invoice #INV-XXXX - Account Name',
  type: 'email',
  mailbox_id: HelpScout.default_mailbox,
  status: 'active',
  customer: { email: 'email@example.com' },
  created_by: 1234,
  threads: [
    {
      type: 'customer',
      customer: { email: 'email@example.com' },
      text: 'A test thread.'
    }
  ]
}

HelpScout::Conversation.create(data)
```

However, this example code will create a new issue in the mailbox queue FROM the customer. Anyone know how to create a new conversation from a Help Scout "user" (our support email) to be sent TO a customer (our client)?

Basically, what params need to be passed to have the API work like how "New Conversation" (new-ticket) works in their Web UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong [thread type](https://developer.helpscout.com/mailbox-api/endpoints/conversations/create/#threads).

To create a new conversation FROM a "user" addressed TO a "customer" your thread should use the "**reply**" type.

```rb
data = {
  subject: 'Time for renewal - Invoice #INV-XXXX - Account Name',
  type: 'email',
  mailbox_id: HelpScout.default_mailbox,
  status: 'active',
  customer: { email: 'email@example.com' },
  created_by: 1234,
  threads: [
    {
      type: 'reply',
      customer: { email: 'email@example.com' },
      text: 'A test thread.'
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks to Kristi at Help Scout for her super quick answer to my question.